# attaching click-handler to image inside table cell that also contains an input checkbox

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I hope you can help me figure this out. I do not understand why the click-handler is being called when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
<tr>
 <td class="lbl">foo</td>
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="checked: foo"/>
    <img alt="?" class="helpimg" id="helpFoo" src="images2\question_mini.gif"/>
   </td>
 </tr>

  $(".helpimg").on("click", function (e) {
             // why is this handler invoked when the checkbox is checked?

                });

  });
```

EDIT:

When I remove the knockout binding, it works properly:

```
data-bind="checked: foo"
```

Comment: works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/CtTLU/

Comment: Work OK here http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/Uw5kT/

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do some digging to see what else is going on.

Comment: It is related to knockout.

Comment: Your code works even with knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/j2u2z/. So your problem is somewhere else.... please create a jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem! Without a way to reproduce your issue your question is off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Knockout, then I would suggest that you use Knockout to handle the click event.

- You just need to add a function to the view model to handle the click event
- Then add `data-bind="click: myFunctionName"` to the `img` tag

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/K8P8Z/1/)

**JavaScript**

```
var vm = {
    foo: ko.observable(true),
    clickImage: function(){
        alert('image clicked');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="lbl">foo</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: foo" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/16x16" data-bind="click: clickImage"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```